# Dart event queue and microtask

Tags: dart, event-loop, dart-async

i am trying to understand, how dart event loop works. I read the event loop article from the website [The Event Loop and Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/) and the author explain pretty good how event loop in dart works.

But what i don't understand is, how event get queue. For example

```dart
new Future(() => 21)
    .then((v) => v*2)
    .then((v) => print(v));
```

Will here dart gonna create three entries in the event queue or just one? I know, that the class Future is responsible for delay execution and when i create an object from it like

```dart
new Future(() => 21)
```

it will be just one entry in the event loop.

In this article, that i have mentioned above, i read about microtask. This microtask is going to execute before event queue, but i don't see any sense, why dart team implement this microtask? Maybe i need some example!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some investigation it appears that the right answer is "they will be executed in the next event loop"

To test it you can write something like this:

```dart
import "dart:async";
void main() {
  new Future(() {
    scheduleMicrotask(()=>print("before loop 1"));
    print("in event loop");
  }).then((_) {
    scheduleMicrotask(()=>print("before loop 2"));
    print("in event loop");
  }).then((_) {
    scheduleMicrotask(()=>print("before loop 3"));
    print("in event loop");
  });
}
```

it should output:

> in event loop
>   in event loop
>   in event loop
>   before loop 1
>   before loop 2
>   before loop 3

Although i'm not sure that you can't break this optimization. So only sure fact is that the first`Future` will complete first and the second - second.

*EDIT: The strange part(**Obsolete**):*

With code like this:

```dart
import "dart:async";
void main() {
  new Future(() {
    scheduleMicrotask(print("before loop 1"));
    print("in event loop");
  }).then((_) {
    scheduleMicrotask(print("before loop 2"));
    print("in event loop");
  }).then((_) {
    scheduleMicrotask(print("before loop 3"));
    print("in event loop");
  });
}
```

output is:

```dart
before loop 1
in event loop
before loop 2
in event loop
before loop 3
in event loop
Unhandled exception:
The null object does not have a method 'call'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'call'
Receiver: null
...
```

But with this:

```dart
import "dart:async";
void main() {
  new Future(() {
    scheduleMicrotask(()=>print("before loop 1"));
    print("in event loop");
  }).then((_) {
    scheduleMicrotask(()=>print("before loop 2"));
    print("in event loop");
  }).then((_) {
    scheduleMicrotask(()=>print("before loop 3"));
    print("in event loop");
  });
}
```

output is:

> in event loop
>   in event loop
>   in event loop
>   before loop 1
>   before loop 2
>   before loop 3

**EDIT2:**

I think i got it. In the first(wrong version) `scheduleMicrotask`  actually never got properly scheduled, but since  Dart has eager argument execution it executes `print()` anyway. So what happens is that all `Future` getting executed in the next event loop and print all text.
That's why output is in call order:

> before loop 1
>   in event loop
>   before loop 2
>   in event loop
>   before loop 3
>   in event loop

and not in the schedule order.

Comment: The second is what is the actual output

Comment: your code misses `() =>`: 
`scheduleMicrotask(() => print("..."));`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks but now I'm puzzled. I'll edit my answer to explain why.

Comment: So am I. I think we can only wait and hope that @lrn takes a look ;-)

Comment: The microtasks are even executed at the end when you duplicate your code to run it twice.

Answer (score 6):

When you do:

```dart
new Future(() => 21)
.then((v) => v*2)
.then(print);
```

- First you call the `new Future(...)` constructor.
  This creates a Future object and schedules a *Timer* to execute the function you give as argument.
- Then you call `then`. This creates a new future (call it future#2) and adds a listener on the first future. No events are scheduled.
- Then you call `then` again. This creates yet another future (future#3) and adds a listener on the future#2. No events are scheduled.
- Then the timer triggers, and the `()=>21` is executed, and the first future is completed with the value 21.
- The listener on the first future is then executed immediately. That calls `(v)=>v*2` with 21, and then completes future#2 with the value 42.
- The listener on future#2 is then executed immediately. That calls `print` with 42, which prints 42 and returns `null`. This completes future#3 with the value `null`.

Future completion is currently done through a "propagate" function that tries to complete as many futures as possible, as long as their listeners are synchronous. That is why completing one future will immediately complete another, without any intermediate microtasks.

Answer (score 1):

The microtask queue is to queue async execution but avoid returning to the main event loop before these microtasks are finished. You can ensure some related activities to be completed entirely even when executed async before other async tasks/events queued in the main queue are executed.

It seems the code executed from `then` like `(v) => v*2` is again executed inside a `Future` because `then` always returns a `Future`.

from https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/

> The microtask queue is necessary because event-handling code sometimes
>   needs to complete a task later, but before returning control to the
>   event loop. For example, when an observable object changes, it groups
>   several mutation changes together and reports them asychronously. The
>   microtask queue allows the observable object to report these mutation
>   changes before the DOM can show the inconsistent state.

How I interpret this description doesn't fit with the results in the tests in @Jare 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little thing to add to previous answers. The 'Event Loop' article explains this behavior pretty well:

> The function that you pass into Future’s then() method executes
>   immediately when the Future completes. (The function isn’t enqueued,
>   it’s just called.)

(https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/)

It means that in above examples there's always one event but many microtasks.