# Dart: Can't understand how async/awaut, Future and Event loop work together

Tags: dart, async-await, future, event-loop

I'm new to Dart. As i understood from some articles and docs (for example [this article](https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/01/futures-isolates-event-loop/)):

1. `async/await` uses the same mechanism as `Future`, and that is FIFO `Event Loop`.
2. `Event Loop` launches after the execution of `main()`.
3. `async` functions runs *synchronously* up to the first `await` keyword. Then they pause the execution, and execution returns to the previous function in call stack.
4. the remaining code is wrapped to the `Future` and queued to the `Event Loop` (most unsure point for me).

Based on these points i expect, that the following code:

```
main() {
  Future(() => print("1"));
  Future(() {
    print("2");
    asyncFunc("2");
  });
  Future(() => print("3"));

  print("main");
  asyncFunc("main");
  print("\nEvent loop starts?\n");
}

asyncFunc(String from) async {
  print("start  [from $from]");
  await (() async => print("middle [from $from]"))();
  print("end    [from $from]");
}
```

Will create something similar to this event queue after *main()* execution:
`future1` -> `future2` -> `future3` -> `end_from_main`
And after execution of `future2`, event `end_from_future2` will be queued to the end:
`future1` -> `future2` -> `future3` -> `end_from_main` -> `end_from_future2`

So result output i expect should be:

```
main
start  [from main]
middle [from main]

Event loop starts?

1
2
start  [from 2]
middle [from 2]
3
end    [from main]
end    [from 2]
```

But in fact it returns:

```
main
start  [from main]
middle [from main]

Event loop starts?

end    [from main]
1
2
start  [from 2]
middle [from 2]
end    [from 2]
3
```

So the conclusion i made: Either `async/await` events has priority over `Fututre`. Either they use diffrent mechanism, unrelated to `EventLoop`. Or maybe i misunderstand something hardly..

Comment: I think you have a good understanding over the nuances, especially if you're new to Dart!  I think that the misunderstanding is that you expect `Future`s to be resolved in a specific order.  I do not believe that there is any specified order for resolving `Future`s relative to each other.  Therefore it seems reasonable to me that `end [from 2]` is printed before `3`.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for answer. Maybe it really doesn't have specific order. But in many articles i read on this topic, it is stated that `Event queue` is exactly a first-in-first-out queue.

Comment: [The default `Future()` constructor schedules a computation using `Timer.run`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/Future.html), so it schedules a 0-second `Timer` that will add an event to the event queue rather than adding to the event queue directly.  If you instead use the `Future.microtask()` constructor, I think you should get the results you expect.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030271/dart-event-queue-and-microtask.

Comment: Many thanks! This removes a lot of my questions. Yes `Future.microtask()` gives results that i expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i think i understood:

- `Future` can represent either *events*  in `Event queue`, either *tasks* in `Microtask queue`.
  (for example: default `Future()` constructor puts *event* to `Event queue`, `Future.microtask()` puts *task* to `Microtask queue`)
- `await` creates `Future.than` callback to recived `Future`.

My topic example explanation:

- First three `Futrue`s put *events* in `Event queue`.
- `Future<void>` created *implicitly* in `await (() async => print("asyncFunc middle"))()` creates "empty" *task* in `Microtask queue` (i assume that all *implicit* `Future`s are scheduled to `Microtask queue`). Than `await` puts remaining instructions (`print("end [from main]")`) as `Future.than` callback to this "empty" *task*.
- When it comes to `Event Loop` it first executes "empty" *task* from `Microtask queue`. Which ended with callback: `print("end [from main]")`.
- And than `Event loop` executes `Event queue`, where second *event* spawns similar "empty" *task* in `Microtask queue`. And that's why `end [from 2]` happens before third `Future`

Comment: Great research! I just didn't get your conclusion about: *await creates Future.than and Future<void> created await (() async => ...)*. Could you clarify these moments please? So far, it seems that Future.then is an asynchronous callback, but await is a synchronous operation and they are looked not interchangeable for me, aren't they?